# Magento 2: Importing Virtual products URL key

Tags: magento2, import, importexport

I'm trying to upload a configurable product with product variations. This did work fine for a while, but now I get this error:

```
1. Specified URL key already exists in rows: 3
```

[image]

If I analyze the function that validates the row (`vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php L:2242`) I can see that Magento builds an array with URL keys that already imported. The first item keeps it's capitals, the second item is all lower case (that's why this line does pass the validator). The third line is also all lowercase because this is already in the array `urlKeys` the validator throws an error.

The product in row 3 is a virtual product. I thought virtual products did not need this URL-key option (this did work fine). Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep `url_key` column blank.
And select `Import Behavior` as `Add/Update`.
Also check your Magento 2 version is `2.0.2` as earlier versions of Magento 2 were having issues with Import feature.

Comment: You're right, this was working in Magento 2.0.0 but stopped working in Magento 2.0.1. I don't know for sure if it's fixed in 2.0.2, I will check this later. For know I reverted my Magento version to 2.0.0.

Comment: It's importing in that case but still, the url_key is empty in the database.